# minimum value of a queue

Tags: c++, struct, queue

i have this code

```
   std::queue<int> q;
/* fill queue ... */
int min_value = INT_MAX;
std::size_t size = q.size();
while (size-- > 0) {
    int x = q.front();
    q.pop();
    q.push(x);
    if (x < min_value)
        min_value = x;
}
```

this code will give the minimum size of a queue (i guess) but wondering how?
we set int min_value = INT_MAX but max is the upper limits of integers? so how the x < min_value (how it is compared to the maxlimit of integer)

can some one explain this code flow please

Comment: Well any value in your queue which is less than INT_MAX will initially be declared the minimum value. On subsequent iterations this value is refined -- if a smaller value is found that's used for future iterations.

Comment: It works a bit [like this](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3au2mtVoT1qzaxefo1_500.gif).

Comment: min_value = INT_MAX is just to make sure it enters x < min_value condition on the first iteration

Comment: @LucasMarcondesPavelski, <= min_value.

Comment: @so if i have a set values (5, 4,3, 1, 2), each of value enters the condition (x< min_value) and atlast 1 will be my result

Comment: am i right? pls jus clarify

Comment: @billa, no in this case 2 will not enter in the condition. Something like this http://architects.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-minimum-and , but instead of taking the first value it makes the min_value be the largest possible integer, entering the contition if any value < MAX_INT. Try to debug the algorithm!